# I have a visa to stay in Mauritius, can I leave to visit another country and return and still stay until the end of my current visa?

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, mauritius

I'm a UK citizen and I'm currently staying in Mauritius on a 120 day tourist  visa until the end of April. I need to fly to another country for two weeks and wondered if anyone knew whether I will be able to return to and re-enter Mauritius and complete my stay in Mauritius until the end of April with my current visa? Or whether I will be refused re-entry at customs when I try to return? There's nothing written anywhere on the government websites saying I cannot make a trip abroad and then return, but it's not clearly written that I can either. Can anyone confirm either way? Thanks.

Comment: What type of visa? UK citizens can normally enter Mauritius visa-free for up to 60 days providing they can show evidence of onward or return travel https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/mauritius/entry-requirements

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have been granted a tourist visa to stay for 120 days in total. This runs until the end of April. I want to fly somewhere in early February, for two weeks, and am trying to find out whether I can return back to Mauritius in the middle of February to stay here until my visa runs out in April.

Comment: usually the distinction is "single entry" vs "multiple entry". Countries don't generally care whether you leave to visit another country, or go home and then come back.